# Create a class, extend from another and call a parent method

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance, superclass

First of all, I took the animals example from the coffeescript site.

I want to simulate next things in javascript:

- Classes
- Public methods only
- Private methods and variables only
- Inheritance
- Call methods from the super class

I think this way to create this is ok, but when I try to get the `move` method from the parent class, always it returns to itself. What I'm doing wrong?

BTW. Which are the best practices to achieve my goal? Is right what I'm doing?

```
var Animal = (function() {
    function Animal() {}

    var _private = {};
    var _public = {
        move: function() {
            console.log('Can move');
        }
    };

    Animal.prototype = _public;
    Animal.prototype.constructor = Animal;
    return Animal;
})();

var Snake = (function(_super) {
    function Snake() {}

    var _private = {};
    var _public = {
        move: function() {
            console.log(Snake._super_.move);
            console.log('Slithering');
        }
    };

    Snake.prototype = _super.prototype;
    Snake._super_ = _super.prototype;
    for(var method in _public) {
        if(Object.prototype.toString.call(_public[method]) === '[object Function]') {
            Snake.prototype[method] = _public[method];
        }
    }
    return Snake;
})(Animal);

var s = new Snake;
s.move();
```

Comment: Could it be that `Snake._super_` refers to `_super.prototype` and `_super.prototype` refers to `_public` which contains the function move which calls `Snake._super_` which refers to.... I believe it is possible that is what is happening. You can try to execute this path by making a small change: `console.log(Snake._super_.move());` which should promptly crash your browser when ran.

Comment: There are many well tested class inheritance implementations out there. For example: http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/. Why create your own with black jack and hookers? :)

Comment: @YuryTarabanko - If there were black jack and hookers to begin with we wouldn't be in this debacle... :) btw, that is an awesome link!

Comment: That's the point, in these times, programmers are used to use a lot of libraries but I'm sure nobody can understand what they really doing. I think creating my own JS code will allow me to understand at my way. Thanks for the link!

Comment: I see. It's good as an exercise. Just do not use it for production :)

Answer (score 3):

This is very well written code in my opinion, with just one small mistake.

I think you got your pointers a little crossed, try this:

```
<script>
var Animal = (function () {
    function Animal() { }

    var _private = {};
    var _public = {
        move: function () {
            console.log('Can move');
            //this just returns a string to show which method was called
            //inside of the child's move function's console.log
            return "super move called";
        }
    };

    Animal.prototype = _public;
    Animal.prototype.constructor = Animal;
    return Animal;
})();

var Snake = (function (_super) {
    function Snake() { }

    var _private = {};
    var _public = {
        move: function () {
            console.log(Snake._super_.move());//Now we can call super's move
            console.log('Slithering');
        }
    };

    //This created the circular reference where Snake._super_ was pointing to
    //Snake.prototype which was causing the error
    //Snake.prototype = _super.prototype;
    Snake._super_ = _super.prototype;

    for (var method in _public) {
        if (Object.prototype.toString.call(_public[method]) === '[object Function]') {
            Snake.prototype[method] = _public[method];
        }
    }
    return Snake;
})(Animal);

var s = new Snake;
s.move();//now this outputs "Can move", "super move called", "Slithering"
</script>
```

Comment: Yeah, but... Your approach is not an **inheritance** it's **composition**.

Comment: @travis-j One more question for you: Add this method to animal _public `getSome: function() { return 1; }` and run this `console.log(s.getSome(), s.move());`, fail?

Comment: Cause he removed inheritance :)

Answer (score 3):

If you are asking for best practices, I'd say take any of ready to go solutions on the web. I prefer this one: http://canjs.us/#can_construct.

A few notices about your approach:

1. It's not reusable. You have to write the same code for every single class. At least you should extract for-loop to make this piece of code reusable.
2. You need to check `_public.hasOwnProperty(method)` to make your code more robust.
3. `toString` and `valueOf` methods require special handling since they are non-enumerable in IE<9.
4. `Snake.prototype = _super.prototype;` is a complete disaster. Since your super class will have all methods of child.

   ```
   var F = function(){};
   F.prototype = _super.prototype;
   Snake.prototype = new F();
   Snake.prototype.constructor = Snake;
   ```